# How to subscribe a slack channel to an individual github issue

Tags: github, slack

I don't want to subscribe a slack channel to all issues on arbitrary third party repositories, just to the particular issues on which my team/organization is involved (contributing to / impacted by), so the usual github integration command `/github subscribe thirdparty/arbitraryrepo issues` does not suffice as it would cause a ton of unwanted noise in the channel. (and the existing label filtering would not cut it)

(Update: there is an open feature request for that https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/1280)

I neither want to forward my personal github subscriptions to the slack channel as there are lots of projects I am individually involved that have nothing to do with my team's work. (e.g. my direct mentions)

Also, subscription should stay despite I leaved the team/company.

A per-issue public RSS/Atom feed would cut it but it does not exist.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of is adding a channel email integration, registering that address to an organization-shared github account and subscribe it to the individual issues we run into.

But this is quite cumbersome (must keep an alternate github logged-in session while browsing, channel readability could be abused to hijack company account, subscriptions can't be managed from the slack channel...) so any different idea would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**As far as I know there is nothing that would suit your need completely** at this moment, but have you considered `labels`?

**#1 option** You could use **filtering based on label** which seems to be the closest:

- That would notify you about all `issues`, `pulls`, `commits`, `releases`, `deployments` that has a given label. Syntax example:

```
/github subscribe repo-owner/repo-name +label:"team-a"
```

- **Pros**: a general filter based on a label name, e.g. `team-a`
- **Cons**:

  - a single label filter only (AFAIK: multiple labels aren't supported but discussed: https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/384)
  - this works only for a label given when issue/PR is created. Not during its existence ("change label" events are not triggered). Known bug (https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/1594) and feature PR is open https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/965

*Note: a workaround to get info about label change in PR: to convert PR to a draft and back (https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/965#issuecomment-1330884166)*

---

**#2 option** Another thing that might be considered is that the account that is used within GitHub Slack app for connecting to Git server will be actually notified also about all its mentions, assignments & reviews! So if you don't use your personal account, you could get generated some related notifications to the whole *team* / other specific user etc.

*EDIT:*

Workaround steps to achieve partially what you want *(but it can be in some conflict with your Slack / GitHub settings that I’m not aware of):*

- Use / create a shared account (or other special account) in GitHub
- In Slack, use this special GitHub account for connecting Slack GitHub app to GitHub *(this enables notifications by default for this account - mentions and assignments).*
- Then, when this GitHub account is assigned / mentioned, you’d automatically get notified (but again, then it would work not just for issues but hypothetically also in PRs etc.) to a dedicated channel where you'd have your GitHub integration set.

  - To auto-assign an issue, you'd have to use e.g. GitHub Actions.

---

*Caveat: But as we discuss, there’s no simple way to achieve your goal completely. To at least get closer to something similar to what you describe and require, you’d need to accept some compromises and extra steps for workaround as it’s unfortunately not currently natively supported. 3rd hypothetical way is to create even more complex mechanisms of filtering & redirecting data which would increase a level of complexity + you'd also need to maintain it (unless you'd already have something similar existing in your infrastructure) and I wouldn't recommend it.*

Comment: Sorry I only detailed this in the github issue: filtering for arbitrary labels in third-party repos would cause an unacceptable spam volume just as no label filtering

Comment: I don't really understand the second option you wrote: you mean I should mention a shared account in the issues I'd like it to subscribe? How would mentions be forwarded to slack? Wouldn't this cause a rude spam for other issue subscribers?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to achieve simply what you seek. Only with some extra noise (create a special label, subscribe for it and agree with other team(s) to use it strictly for issues) OR workarounds…
---
I edited my previous answer to describe more in details the second option I had mentioned. I believe I answer your questions from prev comment, but explicitly and in a few words:
- yes  
- automatically  
- I don't think so (but this is getting subjective)    
 
---
For clarification: are you talking about github.com (and not Enterprise), right?

Comment: Yeah but no, usually we'll subscribe to a issue in a public project that has impacted us but we are not participating in it. We just want to be notified of future discussions and eventual closure so as to plan for dependency upgrades and rollbacks of deployed workarounds. Pushing public projects to set a specific label on arbitrary issues is unviable. Clarification: github.com, no enterprise. Anyway, thanks for sharing your insights!